# Can I add a light fixture (with a switch) to an existing switch/outlet circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I'd like to drywall/finish the 'closet' under my stairs, but I'd like to add a light fixture with a switch inside the closet first.  Inside this closet already, the back of an outlet box and the back of a light switch box (and wiring between them) are accessible.  That switch, which I'll call switch #1, toggles the outlet, which is for the room adjacent to this closet.  I want to add a 2nd switch, inside the closet, which toggles a light in the closet, independently of switch #1.  Is this possible?  (EDIT: Can someone explain and/or show me with a diagram how this might be possible?)

The wires in the circuit are 14/2 with ground.

Basic representation:

[image]

I have a very basic understanding of circuits and I know that black is generally hot and white is generally neutral, so here is what (I think?) is a more correct representation of how it's already wired:

[image]

Comment: Your basic knowledge is correct if you have an available hot and neutral that you can tap and bring into this new area you could install a lamp and either a pull cord type of fixture or for a few dollars more add a light switch next to the storage area.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the reply, I should've clarified and asked specifically *how* can I accomplish it- as far as the wiring setup goes?  The source hot wire seems OK but when I think about connecting the neutral, I feel like I'd be crossing currents and I'm either going to create a short, or the new light is going to *also* turn on by the existing switch #1 which I wouldn't want.  Here's where my confusion is:

https://i.imgur.com/AA6jUsp.png

I could pigtail the black hots in the new switch just fine, but where to correctly connect the new neutral back into the circuit confuses me, thanks!

Comment: The neutrals are pig tailed at the switch the hot is controlled by the switch this is correct you are not crossing them but placing the lamp in parallel with the outlet this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks again.  Last question (probably) - My concern was the return current along the white.  If source current (black) pigtails at my new switch and travels to the already-existing switch#1, wouldn't the returning current after the already-existing switch (white) touch my new closet light on the way back, even if the new switch is off, after the white pigtail?  I apologize if I'm being oblivious here.  Here's what I mean:
https://i.imgur.com/Wy42Mx9.png

Comment: @ps48 No, that's not how electricity works.  For one, current can't flow "backwards".  The voltage on your hot is ~120V (if you're in the US), the voltage on your neutral is ~0V.  Current will only flow from 120 to 0, not the other way around.  Further, current can't flow through an open circuit.  In your 2nd picture, the current will go through the pigtail and back out to the panel (and then to ground).  Where you have a question mark, you have an open circuit with the switch off, and a potential difference of ~120V with it on.

Comment: If I said current goes backwards I apologize, I didn't mean that, I meant after it goes through the black to the existing switch, it would return/continue through the white (I mean, it IS going "back" along the white through the 14/2, that's what I meant!). On that "return trip" along the 14/2, to me, it looked as if the current could go through the white pigtail and then "touch" the new light, even if my new switch is off. Maybe my issue is I'm thinking it acts like water. If it were water, water would touch my new light via return trip along white, even if my new valve/switch were off. :)

Comment: So I'll have to ditch that thinking.  Many tutorial videos on electricity compare current to water! :)

So would the setup I have in my last picture work fine?  New light and new switch would work independently of the existing switch/outlet?  Thanks again you two

Comment: (Aside from the fact that I have not drawn in the ground wires.  Thanks again :))

Comment: I'm going to throw all this into an answer where I can format it more clearly.

Comment: O to 120 is not exactly correct the wave form is sinusoidal and the water pipe correlation works the pressure is like voltage and the current is like the diameter or flow of the pipe , with all devices in parallel they all see the same voltage and the total current is limited by the breaker, 15 amp for 14 awg wire and 20amp for 12 awg wire.

Comment: That's true, but I felt pointing out that AC systems oscillate (and actually swing between +/- 170V, with 120V being an "average") was complicating the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You'll need to tap power at the receptacle box

Since power is coming in at the receptacle end of this circuit according to your diagram, you'll need to tap power to the new switch and light there, as that's the only place in this you'll find always-hot and neutral -- any point from the existing outlet to the existing switch won't have neutral, just always-hot and switched-hot.

Comment: Hi, just for clarification, wouldn't the white be switch-hot regardless of which side of the receptacle I'm on?

https://i.imgur.com/QMA0rbz.png

I'd assumed that the, um, "hotness" of the white would just continue straight on through, even after powering the receptacle, no?  Thanks

Comment: @ps48 -- no, because current flows in loops -- the utility wants their electrons back once they're done doing nice things for you (so to speak ;)

Comment: In that case, can you confirm that this would be the right configuration regarding tap-in position & pigtailing?  Thank you
https://i.imgur.com/SzyJY4Q.png

Comment: @ps48 -- you got it :) right on the money